# Clean the window in swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jradiobutton

I have a group of `jRadioButton` that I created,

each button has an action listener that creates a `JTable`  in a separate window.

I want that when I press another button, the frame will be cleaned and then the other `JTable` to be performed,

```
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
JRadioButton[] jRadioButton = new JRadioButton[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    jRadioButton[i] = new JRadioButton("machine "+i);
    jRadioButton[i].setBounds(x, y, width, height);// x, y, width, height are place parameters
    group.add(jRadioButton[i]);
    frame.getContentPane().add(jRadioButton[i]);
    frame.update(frame.getGraphics());//update the frame and add the buttons
}
```

let's say, I pressed `machine 1` and a table popped up in a different window, now when I press `machine 2` and a different table will pop up I want to clear the new window before the second table is shown.

So my question is, is it possible to clean a window and if yes how?

Comment: I'd consider simply changing the `TableModel` of the previously existing `JTable`..

Answer (score 2):

If the only difference is JTable you can just change the table's model with `theTable.setModel(properJRadioButtonDependentModel)`.

If you have more controls you can either use a CardLayout swapping panels (for each JRadioButton instance you can create a panel and swap them)

OR

remove all controls using removeAll() method of container, add new controls and call

```
container.revalidate();
container.repaint();
```

Comment: the difference between each button is the length of the JTable, and the details.
Stil use the `theTable.setModel(properJRadioButtonDependentModel)`?

Comment: What is the length of JTable and details?

Comment: It depends on the button

Comment: and what should I put instead of  properJRadioButtonDependentModel?

Comment: It depends on details and length of JTable you didn't explain

Comment: for each button the length is different

Comment: so for each button I need to use this answer or there is a way for the whole group?

Comment: I'm really stuck in this can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand your explanation. Just update the question with several examples. I don't understand **length of the table** term. I don't understand what is **the details**. I mentioned all possible ways to do it and kind of tired. Use one of them suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

the table creation

```
public void createMachineTable(int row) {
    model = new DefaultTableModel(col, row);
    table = new JTable(model) {
        /**
         * 
         */
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rows, int columns) {
            if (columns == 0)
                return false;//left side uneditable
            else
                return true;//right side editable
        }
    };
    pane = new JScrollPane(table);// the new window of te table
    getContentPane().add(pane);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500, 600);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(1);

}
```

now, when pressing a different button, the following levels will be applied

```
pane.getViewport().remove( table );
createMachineTable(rowsNumer);
```

the table will be deleted and a new one will be created.